How often do I need to visit the jobsite of a new home build?
I currently live in New Jersey and I want to move to Florida. I am thinking about hiring a builder to build me a new  home on a vacant lot (yet to be purchased) in an over 55 community.
My concern is that I am going to have to be in Florida at least once a month to make sure the  builder is doing a proper job. How often do I need to go to the job site?

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I have worked hard over the years and I have invested well. As such, I want a new home but  your  point is a good one. I  do not see this as an opinion-based question because I  would think  that  there  should be a standard practice in this  area and if so  I  want to know what it is.

You can spend your money however you like - that's what it is for! I know people who have had their custom dream-home built. I know others who made do with a semi-custom new home and I know others who kept searching until they found their used-but-otherwise ideal home already built. But long-distance management of new construction can get complicated.

Isn't this a duplicate? I could swear we addressed "building a house in Florida remotely" before.

I used to work for a custom builder in Fla. The majority of homes we built were for people out of state or out of the country.  We were trusted because the people viewed our model homes and were given a thorough understanding of our building practices and materials. We went above code on many things and did not use inferior materials for the sake of saving money.  That meant we were not inexpensive.  Pick a builder that is not cheap and avoid the big nationwide builders and you can rest easy and inspect once or twice. TBC

Additionally, even if you plan to pay cash for the home, use a bank for a construction loan. You will pay some costs and a little interest, but the bank will send an inspector to verify that work is completed and the county inspector has signed off on any necessary inspections prior to releasing any monies for a draw due. The bank will also not release a final draw without your approval.  (do know that the inspector does not do a complete inspection of every aspect of construction, but does verify that the phase of work outlined for a draw is indeed completed.)

@RMDman: Interesting reason to finance, even if you pay it off immediately! (The other reason is that it can be the safest opportunity for leveraged investment that you will ever have -- but that, and putting enough down to avoid PMI, are better topics for the Money stack.)

A construction loan, must be paid off when the home is complete. A construction/perm loan can be converted to the long-term mortgage when the home is completed.  Either comes with the advantage of the bank working for your protection.  I have heard of builders having conflicts with owners and they ( builders) stop work.  But when the bank is involved builders will work to get conflicts resolved. Builders don't want to be an enemy of the bank.

My two cents as a former builder: You probably don't have the knowledge to do much good on-site. You aren't likely to catch "improper" issues anyway unless they're grievously bad. Write a thorough contract and talk through any fuzzy areas so expectations are set, then trust who you chose. That's all you can do. A good business will be happy to send you regular photo or video updates, too.

Don't start building until you've moved to FL. Rent a house/apartment or stay in a hotel/AirBNB nearby monitoring progress until construction is complete. Consider the rent part of the cost of construction. Consider the peace of mind you gain as a discount.

Either you trust your general contractor, or you hire someone to supervise the supervisor and then worry about trusting them... Ask for daily progress reports, ask for pictures, and eventually someone needs to inspect it and sign off on it.
Short of finding a way to get there more often yourself, or building in a place you can get to, I honestly don't see any other good answers. I mean, you could try to build a telepresence robot or just saturate the site with cheap web cameras, but I honestly don't think either would give you a lot of useful information.
